# Show Var(x) = Cov(x,x) for continuous random variable x, using the integral definition of covariance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance, covariance

We start from the definition of covariance:

$\text{Cov}(X, Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x - \mu_X)(y - \mu_X) f(x,y) \, dx \, dy
$

Plugging in Y = X (abuse of notation):

$\text{Cov}(X, X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x - \mu_X)(x - \mu_X) f(x,x) \, dx \, dx
$

Now, I'm not able to intuitively understand how f(x, x) turns into f(x). Can someone shed some light? Basically, I'm confused as to how the definition of covariance for two different variables generalizes when we're dealing with the same random variable.

Comment: A thought: since x is the same random variable in both cases, then f(x, x) = f(x). But how does the rest of the integral clean up?

Comment: The approach is fundamentally flawed. You can only compute covariance like that for $X,Y$ which admit a joint density. $X,X$ does not

Comment: It's just f(x)and a single integral since you only have one random variable. Putting $f(x)$ in the integral, gives $E(x-\mu_{x})^2$ which is var(x).